# (CloudKit JS) Is it possible upload some file (.zip/.png/..) and that the user can view it?

Tags: javascript, rest, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

Is it possible upload some file (.zip/.png/..) (with CloudKitJS) and that  the user can view it in his/her dashboard https://www.icloud.com/?

Or the stored data (with CloudKit JS) are only available accessing by programming (?)

Thanks for your answers